Trouble opening local file on C# project in VS Code
I've made the simplest program using dotnet new console.
Program.cs contains one line:
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("input.txt").ToString());

input.txt exists in the same folder as Program.cs and contains one line:
Hello, world!

When I execute dotnet run from a console window, I get the desired result: the contents of input.txt is written to stdout.
However I'm getting the following "unhandled exception" when I run the associated project in VS Code:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\Code\newConsole4\bin\Debug\net9.0\input.txt'

How can I make VS Code to read the input.txt file from the same folder where program.cs exists?

Opened folder in VS Code
Selected Run and Debug

EXPECTED: the contents of input.txt written to stdout
OBSERVED:

Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\Code\newConsole4\bin\Debug\net9.0\input.txt'


The issue arises when you run your project in VS-Code using debugger, the working directory is set to the bin/Debug/netX.X/ folder, not the folder containing your Program.cs file. The program looks for input.txt in the working directory, but since it’s in the root project folder, it throws a FileNotFoundException.
You need to ensure input.txt is either copied to the output directory during the build process or you adjust the code to find the file in the correct location.
Simple solution:

Open your input.txt file in the VS Code file explorer.
Add the following line to your .csproj file:

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="input.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>



Save the .csproj file, and rebuild your project using dotnet build.
Run the project in VS Code. It should now locate input.txt.


Thanks, that's a good workaround. Kinda of annoying when I have many input files. Is there any way to achieve what I asked for? Perhaps by editing the launch.json file?
